# C# Found conflicts... circular reference?

Tags: c#, reference

In my solution consisting of ~20 projects, one project gives this build warning:

```
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277: Found conflicts between different versions of "System.Drawing" that could not be resolved.
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277: There was a conflict between "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "System.Drawing, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:     "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "System.Drawing, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Drawing.dll].
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Drawing.dll
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:           Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.8\System.Drawing.dll".
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:             System.Drawing
9>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2364,5): warning MSB3277:     References which depend on "System.Drawing, Version=6.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
```

The references that depend on System.Drawing v6.0.2.0 consist of other projects within the solution, but the project file referring to v4.0.0.0 seems to be itself.  I cannot find any way to prevent this self-reference.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the version 6.0 package to the project with the warning?

Comment: I looked at that and it is a bit confusing.  Looking at NuGet, there is no System.Drawing package, but rather SystemDrawing.Common.  Add that package to the project does not help.  If I look at assembly references, there is a System.Drawing assembly which is included as part of the implicit references which is labelled v4.0.0.0 and I don't see any way to upgrade it.

Comment: Can you add the project file contents to the question?

Comment: Not sure if I can include the full contents.  But, I've tried adding <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing" Version="6.0.0" /> and that doesn't fix the problem.  There are no other references to System.Drawing or System.Drawing.Common in that file.

Comment: I've also tried adding <PropertyGroup>
  <DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>true</DisableImplicitFrameworkReferences>
</PropertyGroup> to the .csproj but that removes all the assembly references in addtiion to System.Drawing and I cannot add them back.  When I go to the Add Assembly Reference dialog, all the implicit framework references are still check and changing any of them leads to no change in the file dependencies.

Comment: I'm thinking that you need to figure out where the 6.0.2.0 reference is coming from.

The System.Drawing.Common nuget package doesn't have any dependencies, does it? System.Drawing.Common shouldn't be causing a conflict with System.Drawing -- they have different names.

Comment: I may have found a fix. I removed 

<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.2.0" newVersion="6.0.2.0" />
 </dependentAssembly>

from the project's app.config file.  Feels a little odd to not enforce the newer version, but somewhere within the project, an older version dependency is causing the conflict.  Is it reasonable to remove this redirect?

Comment: Oh, interesting. Yes, I would not think that is needed unless that dll is in the bin dir after you build. It should be easy to confirm that the application runs/works without the binding redirect, right?

Comment: Builds and runs just fine.  I need to more thoroughly test the drawing functions, but at this point, seemed ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

I may have found a fix. I removed

```
<dependentAssembly> 
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Drawing" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" /> 
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.2.0" newVersion="6.0.2.0" /> 
</dependentAssembly>
```

from the project's app.config file. Feels a little odd to not enforce the newer version, but somewhere within the project, an older version dependency is causing the conflict. Is it reasonable to remove this redirect?

Thanks to @Tenatus for help generating ideas